# Regex capture value within bracket, value contain brackets as well

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, brackets, curly-braces

I want to match the following text:

```
(valuex) AnySingleWord (valuey)
```

I want to capture the text of ***valuex,valuey*** within the brackets. The tough thing is **valuex,valuey** both can contain brackets as well. For example

```
((value1) AnySingleWord (value2)) AnySingleWord ((value3) AnySingleWord (value4))
```

Then my **valuex** should be

```
(value1) AnySingleWord (value2)
```

and **valuey** should be

```
(value3) AnySingleWord (value4)
```

Can regex do something like counting the number of open bracket has passed, and match things until the right close bracket found? many thanks.

PS: I can limit number of open/close bracket pairs to 2-3, if this is small enough to be solvable by Regex

Comment: Related: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/133601/335858).

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of nested brackets? If so, then you can use regex. However, it's probably not the easiest solution.

Comment: @Jerry: You could still get it recursively.

Comment: I can limit number of open/close bracket pairs to 2-3, if this is small enough to be solvable by Regex

Comment: Headline change request. Shouldn't the word 'bracket' be used for '[' and not a '(' (parenthesis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use this pattern:

```
\(((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|[^()]+)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)
```

more informations about this kind of pattern here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx

Comment: This works, many thanks. Great as this is my individual work, otherwise teammate is gonna murder me, or I am gonna frustrating explain Regex balanced matching group.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple way would be as follows if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
1. iterate through characters
2. find first left brace
3. count braces until non-paired right brace appears and store index
4. take the substring from zero to that index and set as value x
5. delete value x substring
6. go to step 1 and store next part as value y
```

Comment: this would be intuitive a non-regex solution, if i can't manage to handle using regex, i would try this

Comment: Sure! It would also be a lot easier to read and debug. It's your choice, but this scenario certainly seems to lend itself to a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be

```
(?<left>\(([^()]*(\([^()]*\))?[^()]*)+\))[^()]*(?<right>\([^()]*((\([^()]*\))?[^()]*)+\))
```

Your code would be

```
Match m=Regex.Match(inp,reg);
m.Groups["left"].Value;//left value
m.Groups["right"].Value;//rightvalue
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly Casimir's solution is shorter, thanks for the help again